# Bcrypt hash function returns undefined result

Tags: javascript, express, bcrypt

In a controller I'm trying to create a hash and save it with the user, using this section of code.

```
router.post('/', (req, res)=>{
   console.log(req.body.password, process.env.SALT_ROUNDS);
   bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, process.env.SALT_ROUNDS, function (err, hash) {
        if(err) {
           res.status(500);
        }  
        console.log("hash ", hash, req.body.password);
        // await req.context.models.User.create({
        //     username: req.body.username,
        //     email: req.body.email,
        //     password: hash })
        //       .then(function(data) {
        //           console.log("user saved")
        //           if (data) {
        //           res.send(data);
        //       }
        //  });
   });
});
```

But the result of the callback function inside `hash` argument is undefined. Here are the logs.

> asd123 10
>
> hash  undefined asd123

Where is the problem, that hash is undefined ?

Comment: This is a case of callback functions and variable scope.  The variable `hash` is available in the callback function which is the third parameter in your `bcrypt.hash` call.  If you want to log the value of `hash` move your `console.log` inside the callback function and you'll see the value.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to use promises `bcrypt` is compatible with them and can be used with `async/await` as seen in the docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt  If you want a further explanation I can go into in more detail in a proper answer

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - Ahh, I had a wrong formatting which was misleading. I edited. It is inside of the callback actually.

Comment: This is very odd.  By all accounts the code should be working best I can tell.  Have you already checked the developer tools in Chrome when you hit that URL to see if there are any errors shown in there?  Can you also post the Node version you are running and the bcrypt version as well?  Maybe a compatibility issue?

Comment: I'm sry... I reimplemented your Code and it just runs fine... 
Output:
`test 10
hash  $2b$10$JV2YKpfqlpJin2JpuMexKOCeZ7SrVyLtmTWM43GXmNmrtoMi8l6yu test`
As @MichaelPlatt says please look at the Network tab of Chrome to see if you get maybe a 500 error...

Comment: I'm using Postman and looking at node console.logs. Maybe something is happening along the code flow. I'm working and try to figure it out. Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: No problem!  Can you check your versions to make sure they are compatible though?  On the official `npm` site, `bcrypt` has a list of versions compatible with node that could help understand the problem a bit more.  Also, if you just run the application and go to the browser and check out the Chrome tab it will help debugging a lot too.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt - checked it node is `v10.13.0` , bcrypt is `bcrypt@3.0.6` . The docs says for node 10, 11 is bcrypt >= 3

Comment: Cool.  So only other thing to do would be to check the tab in Chrome and see what's going on.  You can run the application locally and do that if you see some errors post them up here and we can take a look and try to help out further.

Comment: Omg ... figured it out, posted it as an answer. It was a very silent error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `process.env.SALT_ROUNDS` was a string and I didn't quite understood that from the returned result. When I parse it to number `+process.env.SALT_ROUNDS` it worked.

> asd123 10
>
> hash  $2b$10$Ty3JNeIBXUizrS85MsH8H.oTNsRtXzdiv9ZdamxnG7CmPD2CjSZG2 asd123